# How to record and replay mouse activity on automator in the background?

Tags: mac, automator

I want to create an "application" in Automator for recording mouse actions. When it is run, i want it to execute the actions in the background, like it happens when a macro is run in excel, rather than simply replaying it like a movie. Is this possible?

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: trying to open the preferences of a menu bar item to clear the entries in it.

Comment: What menu bar item?

Comment: Copyclip 2 > Preferences > advanced> clear all clips

Comment: Please see the **Update Note:** to my answer.

Comment: I changed the bash script code a bit, so please see the Update Note: to my answer, again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. It works well. Just what i was looking for. However, you mentioned that you use Spotlight search to find and execute the bash code. Rather, I have found out a workaround to assign a shortcut to the code. Once we have done what you have suggested (i.e. to create an automator executable application of the bash code), then, to create another automator Service with the following :

Comment: Get Specified Finder Items (add the earlier created application to the list), then Open Finder Items. Then change the : Service receives dropdown to "no input" . Finally go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shorcuts > Services > General ..and assign a suitable shortcut for the service. Btw, thanks a lot user3439894 for your research and time taken to solve my query.

Comment: murgaa is awesome, but it plays like a movie :) (maybe, consider it as a Plan B)
http://www.murgaa.com/macro-recorder-mac/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Note:**

My original answer, shown further below, was written using a *generic example* and not the actual target because it had not yet been disclosed. Once it was disclosed, in a comment, I downloaded **CopyClip 2** and wrote the **AppleScript** *code* using **UI Scripting** to bring up the **Advanced Preferences** *pane*, *click* the **Delete All Clips** *button*, the subsequent **Delete All** *button*, *close* the **Preferences** window, and *close* the **UI** that shows the clips. It works, however it's **UI Scripting** and you see it as though manually done, but it happens much faster and without seeing visual mouse movements across the screen. (Not really a *background* solution.)

That said though, I found **CopyClip 2** to be very unstable and crashed every other or few times I ran the *script*, and why I'm not posting the *code* unless you really want to see it. So I don't recommend the **UI Scripting** method. Note that the instability expressed was just in conjunction with using **AppleScript** on the app and not the overall use of it. (I actually have not used it other then to answer the question.)

**Looking now for a *background* solution**, I investigated how **CopyClip 2** stores the clips, and found where the clip datastore was and in what form. Not surprisingly, it's stored in an **SQLite** database. So with that information, I see two different options:

The first involves manipulating the data stored in the **SQLite** database. The problem there is, I don't do **SQL** programming, so you'd have to pursue that option on your own.

The second option is more of a quasi-brute-force method but it works well and did't crash the app in the process. It involves programmatically quitting **CopyClip 2**, deleting the clip database, and restarting **CopyClip 2**.

Either of these option would be considered the *background method*, especially when compared to using **UI Scripting**.

The following *example* **BASH** *script code* is what I used for the second option mentioned. It can be run in a number of different ways.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$(pgrep "CopyClip 2")" ]; then
    pkill "CopyClip 2"
    sleep 1.5
    for i in $HOME/Library/Containers/com.fiplab.copyclip2/Data/Library/Application\ Support/CopyClip/*; do
        rm "$i" 2>/dev/null
    done
    open -a "CopyClip 2"
fi
```

I first tested this a half dozen or so times in **Terminal** as an executable **BASH** *script* before I used the *code* in a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *application*, and tested another half dozen or so times. For my 2 cents worth, this is the way I'd go over trying to do the **SQL** programing option even if I knew **SQL**.

Saved as an **Automator** *application*, e.g., **Delete All CopyClip Clips**, I used **Spotlight** to find and execute it, i.e.:

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The *application* could also be placed in the **Dock** for a *quick mouse click* to delete all the clips too.

By the way, I also have **Hide window as startup** set to **ON** on the **General** tab in **Preferences** for **CopyClip 2**, so as to make this as *background* as possible in appearance. This way, unless you're looking directly at the **Menu bar** icon for **CopyClip 2**, you don't really notice it's been closed and reopened.

Also, note that the clip database is normally created upon first run and only changes as clips are stored or deleted through **CopyClip 2**. I examined the clip database using [**SQLiteBrowser**](http://sqlitebrowser.org) when first created and after deleting all the clips and its structure is essentially no different then when first created<sup>1</sup>, so repeatedly deleting the clip database really isn't a problem to achieve the goal. 
<sub>*(<sup>1</sup> While technically there are some differences, the deleted data had not be removed from the database by the VACUUM command yet, nonetheless this option is extremely safe and should not be problematic with repeated use.)*</sub>

---

**Original Answer:**

Using the **Record** *button* in **Automator**, you've recorded some *mouse clicks* on the **Menu bar** and this produced a **Watch Me Do** *action* in the *workflow*. Subsequently running the **Automator** *workflow* containing the **Watch Me Do** *action*, to use your words, it plays like a movie.

So you are asking if this can run in the background more like an **Excel** *macro* then play like a movie?

Generally speaking, the short answer is both yes and no... yes more like a macro (sort of), but no not in the background.

That said, note however and depending on the target application and what needs to be done, there may be the possibility of coding something to perform in the background but without knowing the explicit specifics it's beyond the scope of  this generally speaking short answer.

The longer answer is, to convert the **Watch Me Do** *action* into appropriate **AppleScript** *code*. However, because it uses **UI Scripting** it cannot run in the background, but it can run much more efficiently and faster then a **Watch Me Do** *action* played back and you do not see the visual mouse movements across the screen. This means that when the **AppleScript** *code* is run, by whichever means one choose, one has to allow the *script* to process its *code* uninterrupted, thus being one of the drawbacks of **UI Scripting**.

However, I believe you'll find this more desirable then playing like a movie and seeing the mouse visually move across the screen.

As an example, recording my actions while using the **Clock** on the **Menu bar** in this example, I'm going to *click* the **Clock** *menu item*, then *click* the **Open Date & Time Preferences…** *menu item*, then *click* the **Close** *button* on the **Date & Time Preferences** *pane* of **System Preferences**, which is opened as a result of the two previous *clicks*.

In **Automator**, I select the three **Events** in the **Watch Me Do** *action*, then press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to *copy* the *events* to the clipboard.

Now I *open* **Script Editor** and in a *new document*, *press* <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to *paste* the copied *events* from the clipboard.

This produces the **AppleScript** *code* shown at the very end of this answer, which is placed there because not much of it will actually be used, but it will have the key pieces of *code*, so not having to manually type all of the finished code and is only included herein for completeness of this example case.

Within the pasted *code* there are three *commands* that represent the actual *click events*, and since this is using **UI Scripting** it's being done by **System Events**.

So, in another *new document*, in **Script Editor**, I add a `tell application "System Events"` *block*, e.g.:

```
tell application "System Events"

end tell
```

Within that *tell block*, I copied the appropriate portion of the three *click events* from the *code* pasted in the other document while removing the unnecessary *code* and *backslashes* for this use case, e.g.:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu bar item 7 of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer"
    click menu item 6 of menu 1 of menu bar item 7 of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer"
    click UI element 1 of window "Date & Time" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell
```

Now because this is **UI Scripting**, appropriate `delay` *commands* need to be added, e.g.:

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu bar item 7 of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer"
    delay 0.5
    click menu item 6 of menu 1 of menu bar item 7 of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer"
    delay 2.5
    click UI element 1 of window "Date & Time" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell
```

Now while I could run the *code* above (or even the originally pasted *code*) and it should function properly at this time, the problem is that `menu bar item 7`, which is currently the **Clock** on my system, can change. So too in some cases, can the `menu item n` change as well, although not in this example use case. However, knowing this, lets rewrite the *code* so it's not *hard coded* for the *menu bar item number* or the *menu item number*:

```
tell application "System Events"
    -- click menu bar item 7 of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer"
    click (every menu bar item of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer" whose description is "clock")
    delay 0.5
    -- click menu item 6 of menu 1 of menu bar item 7 of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer"
    click (every menu item of menu 1 of (every menu bar item whose description is "clock") ¬
        of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer" whose title is "Open Date & Time Preferences…")
    delay 2.5
    -- click UI element 1 of window "Date & Time" of application process "System Preferences"
    -- click button 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
    quit application "System Preferences"
end tell
```

In the *code* above, the original three lines of *code* have been commented out, i.e. `--` was added in front of each line. Also, the original third line has an additional line under it commented out, but was added to show how to generalize the original third line. However, since its purpose in this example was to *close* **System Preferences**, just tell it to *quit* instead.

So the final example version of the *code* to handle the three *events* that took place in the example **Watch Me Do** *action* in **Automator** is:

```
try
    tell application "System Events"
        click (every menu bar item of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer" whose description is "clock")
        delay 0.5
        click (every menu item of menu 1 of (every menu bar item whose description is "clock") ¬
            of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer" whose title is "Open Date & Time Preferences…")
        delay 2.5
        quit application "System Preferences"
    end tell
end try
```

Now comparing this final example version of the *code* above to the original *code* shown below, one can see the difference and what's necessary to cleanup the original *code* while not *hard coding* the *menu bar item number* or the *menu item number*, thus making it more intelligent then using the **Watch Me Do** *action* in **Automator**.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above is just that, and sans wrapping it in a `try` *statement*, does not include any other *error handling* as may be appropriate/needed/wanted, the onus is upon the user to add any appropriate *error handling* for any *example code* presented and or *code* written by the oneself. This includes setting the *value* of the `delay` *commands* as appropriate for the timing on ones own system.

Additionally, not all *menu items* are as easily scripted as this example case and in some cases may not work well to even use this method, it just depends and is one of the reasons I was trying to get more explicit and specific information from you in my comments. That is, I might have been able to give you explicit and specific *code* for your immediate need, rather then having to write an answer using an example. Although, hopefully this example with be useful to may others as well.

---

Original **AppleScript** *code* generated when *events* were copied and pasted from the **Watch Me Do** *action* in **Automator** for this example use case:

```
-- Click the “clock” menu bar item.
delay 0.249747
set timeoutSeconds to 0.500000
set uiScript to "click menu bar item 7 of menu bar 1 of application process \"SystemUIServer\""
my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

-- Open Date & Time Preferences…
delay 0.186764
set timeoutSeconds to 0.500000
set uiScript to "click menu item 6 of menu 1 of menu bar item 7 of menu bar 1 of application process \"SystemUIServer\""
my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

-- Click the “<fill in title>” button.
delay 0.509640
set timeoutSeconds to 0.500000
set uiScript to "click UI Element 1 of window \"Date & Time\" of application process \"System Preferences\""
my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```